# How to pass a member function as a parameter to a function that doesn't expect it?

Tags: c++, bind, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Say I have a function `foo`:

```
void foo(void (*ftn)(int x))
{
  ftn(5);
}
```

It needs as a parameter a `void` function that accepts an int as a parameter. Consider

```
void func1(int x) {}

class X {
public:
  void func2(int x) {}
};
```

Now 
`foo(&func1)` is ok.

But `foo(&X::func2)` isn't ok because `X::func2` isn't static and needs a context object and its function pointer **type** is different.

I tried `foo(std::bind(&X:func2, this))` from inside `X` but that raises a type mismatch too.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Consider changing your function to take a `std::function` as it's argument. That way you can use `std::bind` to transparently use either a free function, static member function, or non-static member function.

Comment: template function foo is most likely the easiest solution to go with. Edit: Yes as mentioned above, even easier may be std::function

Comment: What if I'm not allowed to change `foo` (part of a library) ?

Comment: It helps to remember `void (*ftn)(int x)` as *just* an address of a function that takes a single `int`. You cannot call `X::func2` if you just know the method's address. You do need the method's address, but you need more than just that (you need an object instance), so it clearly cannot fit in a single `void (*)(int)` value. There's just no way around that. You *might* use additional global variables (`X *x; void x_func2(int y) { x->func2(y); }`, and set `x` to a sensible value), but it's a solution that doesn't scale. (I know I'm not using terms in the same sense as the C++ standard here.)

Comment: Is that function pointer the **only** argument to `foo`?  Show us the real declaration of the library function.

Comment: @hvd can you write that as an answer. I find the part that the address alone isn't sufficient to be very helpful.

Comment: @robmayoff, yes. Actually it is a C-library. So that is why they haven't cared much about this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, if you cannot change the signature of `foo` to take anything but a raw function pointer... then you'll have to do something like this:

```
struct XFunc2Wrapper {
    static X* x;

    static void func2(int v) {
        x->func2(v);
    }
};
```

And then just do `foo(&XFunc2Wrapper::func2)` once you set `XFunc2Wrapper::x` to be your `X`. It doesn't have to be nested in a struct, it can just be some global pointer, but nesting helps establish the intent behind the code better.

But this should definitely be last resort after (as per Captain Obvlious) trying to do `foo(std::function<void(int)> )`.