# How do I use bind to pass a member function as a function pointer?

Tags: qt, c++11, stdbind

I'm trying to pass a member function as a function pointer so that I don't need to rely on singletons or global functions to handle Qt messages in Qt 5. As far as I can tell my std::function is of the correct type, it has the correct signature, and bind should be allowing me to jam in the implicit `this` pointer, essentially passing off a member function as a global/un-owned function.

```
void ProgramMessageHandler::setAsMessageHandlerForProgram() {
    std::function<void(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &)> funcPtr;

    funcPtr = std::bind(handleMessages, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);

    qInstallMessageHandler(funkPtr);
}
```

This doesn't compile. I can succesfully create my `funcPtr` variable but passing it into the `qInstallMessageHandler` function causes the following:

```
log\ProgramMessageManager.cpp:16: error: cannot convert 'std::function<void(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)>' to 'QtMessageHandler {aka void (*)(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)}' for argument '1' to 'void (* qInstallMessageHandler(QtMessageHandler))(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)'
 oldHandler = qInstallMessageHandler(hackedPointerToHandleFunction);
                                                                  ^
```

I have read:

[how to pass a member function as a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402195/how-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-function-pointer)

[How do you pass a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer)

[How to pass a member function as a parameter to a function that doesn't expect it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691656/how-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-parameter-to-a-function-that-doesnt-expect-i)

[Get function pointer from std::function when using std::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938774/get-function-pointer-from-stdfunction-when-using-stdbind)

but none have helped me.

**EDIT:**

So it has been said that this isn't possible without a singleton or a global funtion... but why? The only difference between a member function and a global function with the same signature is that they *don't* have the same signature, there is an implicit `this` pointer as the first parameter to a member function.

Knowing that, why cannot I use `std::bind` to bridge this gap, by saying 'I know that the function being called takes the `this` argument before all of the others, force it in there, be the thing that knows about `this`. That would be so much cleaner than a singleton and a global function is just crap.

Comment: A function pointer (unlike a function object) can have no state of its own so there is nowhere to "jam" in a `this` pointer.

Comment: @ChrisDrew but isn't my `std::function` keeping track of it? I was under the impression that `std::bind` was able to bind together things that were not the same by keeping track of *extra* information, e.g. a `this` pointer...

Comment: Yes, a `std::function` could keep track of it. But `qInstallMessageHandler` doesn't take a `std::function` it takes a function pointer.

Comment: @ChrisDrew so is there not a function pointer to a function inside the `std::function` which when called relays the call ++additional information to my member function?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible without singletons or global functions.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I still can't see why it shouldn't be possible, see my edit =]

Comment: Bind works syntactically different from what you want, since it returns an object and not a function pointer. You can store the memberFunction + instance pair using bind, but in order to activate the memberFunction call you have to call a member operator () on the std::function object, which is different that calling a function through a function pointer. That is why your compiler complains. Theoretically you could store the call to operator () inside another function X and pass X to qInstallMessageHandler, but again, there you have a global function that you wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass a **class instance** where a **function pointer** is expected, while no such conversion exists.

You could do something like this:

```
class ProgramMessageHandler
{
  static void  myMessageHandler(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &);
};
```

in main.cpp (for example):

```
...
qInstallMessageHandler(ProgramMessageHander::myMessageHandler);
...
```

You still might have to deal with some issues as in singleton classes, but I think it makes sense that there is one message handler or at least one dispatcher that would somehow redirect different message to appropriate handlers. Hope this helps

Comment: I was hoping that by using `std::bind` I could expose my instance function pointer as a function pointer and then shoehorn in the `this` argument after the call. After all `std::function<void(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &)>` has the correct function signature (i.e. not an instance signature, as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Troyseph `std::bind` does not return a function pointer it returns a function object.

Comment: @ChrisDrew from which I can't get a function pointer? is my issue that my `std::function` cannot be a tempory?

Comment: @Troyseph: No, if that was possible the C++ Standard wouldn't have bothered to introduce `std::function`, and `std::bind` would have returned a function pointer straight away. Heck, a _member_ function pointer usually is bigger than an ordinary function pointer anyway as it needs to have `virtual`-ness information embedded. It couldn't even fit.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `std::bind` is a function object and, as the error message says, you cannot convert a function object to a function pointer. A function pointer cannot store the `this` pointer like `std::function` can, you can't just "force it in there".

The only way to do something approaching what you want is to use a singleton to store the `this` pointer:

```
class ProgramMessageHandler {
private:
  static ProgramMessageHandler* currentHandler;
  void handleMessagesImpl(const std::string& message);
public:
  void setAsMessageHandlerForProgram(){
    currentHandler = this;
    qInstallMessageHandler(handleMessages);
  }
  static void handleMessages(const std::string& message) { 
    if (currentHandler) 
      currentHandler->handleMessagesImpl(message);
  }
};

ProgramMessageHandler* ProgramMessageHandler::currentHandler = nullptr;

int main() {
  ProgramMessageHandler handler;
  handler.setAsMessageHandlerForProgram();

  // trigger messages...
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OGt8kBrRBewAiBqj).

Comment: Almost exactly the solution I settled on, why Qt is using C style syntax in a 2015 C++ library beats me... very annoying!

Comment: I guess that what I was really hoping for was that `function` object owned a function pointer, that I could pass as normal, which was bound to my member function through `bind` shenanigans... alas tis not the case.

Comment: To your question regarding why do they use such syntax, I would assume just because it saved them the work of rewriting tons of source code maybe... qInstallMessageHandler is a replacement for an older function, qInstallMsgHandler, which was introduced in qt 4.8, which was released in December 2011, only a couple of months after C++ 11 was approved (August 2011) .

Comment: The "why" is easy. Qt supported building with compilers w/o C++/11 support until quite recently, I _think_ 5.7 was the first to require that. And within a release cycle, source compatibility is promised, so it cannot be modified before Qt 6. And then there is still discussion if Qt can use std like std::function in its ABI, because of binary compatibility concerns.