# Why calling a singleton class Qt Message Handler member function gives error: missing argument list?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to direct the Qt debugging messages into a text log file. while trying to install the message handler function i have written, the following error occurred:

`main.cpp: error: C3867: 'Log::myMessageHandler': function call missing argument list; use '&Log::myMessageHandler' to create a pointer to member`

please note that :

1. I have declared the message handler function `myMessageHandler` as a member function in the **singleton** `Logger` class.
2. The `myMessageHandler` function was accessed using the static method `ReturnInstance()`.
3. The function `myMessageHandler` was installed in the **main function** of my application using `qInstallMessageHanler()` function.

The code is as follows:

```
/****************************Log.h***********************/    
class Log : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //class member declaration 

    static Log& ReturnInstance()
    {
       static Log Log_obj;   //The only Log object that will be used
       return Log_obj;
    }
    void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type,QMessageLogContext &context,const QString &msg);
    private:
    //some member variable declartion
    QFile m_file;

};
/****************************Log.cpp***********************/
//constructor definition
//destructor definition
void Log::myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{

QTextStream ostream(&m_file);

switch (type) {
case QtDebugMsg:
    ostream<<("Debugging Message: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n"  , msg, context.file, context.line, context.function);
    break;
case QtInfoMsg:
    ostream<<("Information Message: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", msg, context.file, context.line, context.function);
    break;
case QtWarningMsg:
    ostream<<("Warnning Message: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n"   , msg, context.file, context.line, context.function);
    break;
case QtFatalMsg:
    ostream<<("Fatal Message: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n"      , msg, context.file, context.line, context.function);
    break;
case QtCriticalMsg:
    ostream<<("Critical Message: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n"   , msg, context.file, context.line, context.function);
    break;
default:
    break;
  }
}
```

And here is the installation of the message handler function:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "logger.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Log::ReturnInstance();         
    qInstallMessageHandler(Log::ReturnInstance().myMessageHandler);    //<------ The error
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use bind to pass a member function as a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583771/how-do-i-use-bind-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-function-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to pass a pointer to a member function into `qInstallMessageHandler()`. You really need to pass either (1) a `static` member or (2) a globally scoped non-member function.

The error message is a bit cryptic, but the "use '&Log::myMessageHandler' to create a pointer to member" part gives a hint of the problem. A member function pointer really needs an object (hidden `this` pointer) to be called.

Try something more like this:

**Method 1: Static member function**

```
class Log : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type,QMessageLogContext &context,const QString &msg)
    {
        // message handling code...
    }

private:
    //some member variable declartion
    QFile m_file;
};
```

**Method 2: Global function**

```
static void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    // message handling code...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...

    qInstallMessageHandler(Log::myMessageHandler);
    // OR
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);

    //...
}
```

Comment: I have made it static as mentioned above, but the error  error: C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Log::m_file' appeared. I tried to solve it by making the   QFile m_file  static one , this reduced the error to main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class QFile Log::m_file" (?m_file@Log@@0VQFile@@A)

Comment: When you add a static variable to a class, you also have to declare it outside the class:

// Header File (MyClass.h)
class MyClass
{
 private:
  QFile m_file;
}


// Source File (MyClass.cpp)
#include "MyClass.h"

QFile MyClass::m_file;